# Is it approprate to ask "Why was this closed" questions here?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

So, I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807036/let-microsoft-know-that-they-need-to-add-windows-ce-support-back-into-2010-clos) that was closed.  I disagree that this question should have been closed.  I also think it is unfair that it was closed by only 2 people (sure one was a moderator, but lets let the system work.)

So, I want to know:

**First**, is it kosher to ask questions like "why was this closed" (or more directly, "was it fair that this was closed".

And **second**, is my question really "off-topic".  The close reason says:

*Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to programming or software development in some way, within the scope defined in the faq.*

My question is clearly "*Related to [...] Software development in some way*" (it is about Visual Studio support for Compact Framework).

So, assuming the first part of my question is "yes", then was it just that this question was closed?  And if so, how is my question not related to software development in some way?

Comment: "within the scope defined in the faq"

Comment: @mmyers - But the faq just says that it can't be subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion.  (Which it was not.)   Either way, It is clear that most people think that I need to head over to programmers.stackexchange, so that is where I will go.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on meta.meta.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Andreas - I think you just asked a meta-meta-meta question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fist, yes, it's OK to ask why your question was closed on MSO.

Addressing your question, it was closed because it was a question about requesting functionality from Microsoft. While that's not purely off-topic for SO, it is out of scope.

Your title was also a problem.

> *Let Microsoft Know that they need to add Windows CE support back into 2010?*

This sounds like a statement, not a question. Most people wouldn't read the body of your question at all with this title. Frankly, I would have just read the title and voted to close as "not a real question".

I have two suggestions:

1. You might try asking "How do I ask Microsoft to add a feature to VS?"
2. You could try asking on programmers.stackexchange.com instead, as it may be more on-topic for that site.

Comment: For your first suggestion, should I re-ask or hope that a changed title might result in a re-opening?

Comment: @Vaccano - Don't reask on SO - that's heavily frowned upon. You would want to edit and hope for reopen votes. Posting on programmers.stackexchange.com, though, might yield better results.

Comment: OK.  (thought so about the re-asking)  I will head over to programmer.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 6):

I am going to answer this by asking:

> Where is the code?

The question IMHO has nothing to do with a programming problem. You want Microsoft to put support for a specific device back into Visual Studio 2010. Great.

Do you really think by posting the question on SO, Microsoft is going to suddenly do it?

I agree with the moderator in this case, and definitely do not agree that the question was related to a programming problem. Microsoft decided to remove support for a device OS they no longer develop or support. It's a discussion best left for sites like Microsoft Connect or even something to take up with a Microsoft representative or MVP.

Comment: But, the close reason says "related to programming or software development".  Clearly this was not a "programming" question. But am I off base in assuming that it fit the second criteria?

Comment: @Vaccano IMO you off base. The problem is **NOT** a programming problem. A product development has reach the end of it's support lifecycle. No amount of programming is going to solve that problem.

Comment: @Diago: while I agree that petitioning for support or bug fixes on SO is off-topic (and likely futile as well), asking for help finding support for a programming tool seems reasonable (especially since MS seems to keep Connect unnecessarily obscure).

Comment: @Vaccano,@Shog9: questions about development environment is not directly related to "programming or software development"; they are related to the processes around software development. Since SO is getting very large, this kind of very fine distinctions is necessary to keep the site from being useful.

Comment: @Lie The issue that I have with keeping IDE questions seperate is that on SU, nobody will notice them and you don't get any answers. Programmers.SE is not the right place. But on SO about *software development* (Yes, an editor/IDE is part of software development unless your narrowing the definition to theory) and has all the programmers that use such a tool, you get tons of useful answers and can still stay withing the faq

Comment: @TheLQ: Yes, but we need to find all the reasons we can to minimize the number of questions on SO, since that place is flooded already; we do that by moving questions that are only slightly relevant to programming out from SO. If neither SU nor Programmers are appropriate, then probably someone should create ProgrammerTools.SE?

Comment: @Lie Ryan: dev tool questions have been on-topic pretty much since SO's inception. Why should we start disallowing them *now*?